# sequence generator in plsql code in oracle apps

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a sample table like below

```
PO_HEADER ||    ITEM   || LINE_NUM

   1              X 
   1              Y 
   1              Z 
   1              A 
   1              B
```

I want to update sequence number's in line_num column , like 1...5. , and when i enter another line , next sequence number should be generated automatically like 6 in line_number column.

I want to write the code to update the sequence numbers in line_num, & also to capture the next sequence number . So that when i enter the new line , I should get the next sequence number

Comment: Please show us what you have done or achieved so far.

Comment: `So that when i enter the new line , I should get the next sequence number`, how you are entering new line.  Does it via `INSERT` statement or by other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d6ff/1

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ("PO_HEADER" int, "ITEM" varchar2(1), "LINE_NUM" int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 ("PO_HEADER", "ITEM", "LINE_NUM")
         VALUES (1, 'X', NULL)
    INTO Table1 ("PO_HEADER", "ITEM", "LINE_NUM")
         VALUES (1, 'Y', NULL)
    INTO Table1 ("PO_HEADER", "ITEM", "LINE_NUM")
         VALUES (1, 'Z', NULL)
    INTO Table1 ("PO_HEADER", "ITEM", "LINE_NUM")
         VALUES (1, 'A', NULL)
    INTO Table1 ("PO_HEADER", "ITEM", "LINE_NUM")
         VALUES (1, 'B', NULL)
SELECT * FROM dual
;

create sequence alamakota;
```

---

and now:

```
update table1 set LINE_NUM = alamakota.nextval;

select * from table1;

| PO_HEADER | ITEM | LINE_NUM |
|-----------|------|----------|
|         1 |    X |        1 |
|         1 |    Y |        2 |
|         1 |    Z |        3 |
|         1 |    A |        4 |
|         1 |    B |        5 |
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked. but i have a requirement that i have missed out in question.

Comment: as in the above scenario , we have only 1 po_header. but it i have different po_headers like                                                                          | PO_HEADER | ITEM | LINE_NUM |
|-----------|------|----------|
|         1 |    X |        1 |
|         1 |    Y |        2 |
|         2 |    Z |        1 |
|         2 |    A |        2|
|         3 |    B |        1 |

Comment: 1 AAA                                                1
1 BBB                                                2
2 CCC                                                1
2 DDD                                                2

Answer (score 0):

People usually use a sequence (Oracle object) which provides uniqueness but is (generally speaking) not gapless. Sequence is easy to implement; you'd either call it during insert, or create a database trigger which would set column value to the next sequence number.

If you insist on "MAX + 1" option, note that it is about to fail in a multi-user environment - two or more users fetch the same MAX value, depending on `COMMIT` moment and column uniqueness (primary/unique key, unique index) the first one will succeed and everyone else's insert will fail.

There's a workaround - additional table whose *sequence number* is maintained through an autonomous transaction function.

If you're on 12c, use the identity column. Otherwise, I'd suggest a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a sequence for this.

If there is a parent table, to which `PO_HEADER` is a foreign key, grab a lock on the parent row.  Then, `SELECT MAX(line_num)+1...` for that PO and use it.  Do not release the lock on the parent table until you commit your insert to `TABLE1`.

If you do not have a parent table, you can use `DBMS_LOCK` to accomplish the same thing.  (Allocate a user lock representing the PO and lock it in lieu of a parent table).

Since your application is well designed and *all* `TABLE1` inserts happen through this code, you know it will work.  The lock on the parent table ensures two sessions do not get the same next line number because the lock forces them to act one after the other.

If you application is not so well designed, this won't help you.